# Python script writes to file when run in IDE but not in terminal

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to use an OS task scheduler on raspberry pi to run a python script every hour that will take a reading and write to a file. I'm getting a strange issue where if I run the file from my Thonny IDE, the script writes to a file as intended. However, running the script from bash, as the OS scheduler does, gives me my print output in the terminal window but doesn't write to the file. What could be the reason for this?

Here's what I get in the terminal, same as the IDE, showing that program is executing just fine:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3.4 /home/pi/python/TempHumidityCollection.py
2017-11-10 17:10:02.275003
Temperature in Celsius is : 22.75 C
Relative Humidity is : 34.20 %
```

Here's the code for reference:

```
from si7021 import *
from datetime import datetime
import schedule
import time

print(str(datetime.now()))
temp = getTempC()
humidity = getHumidity()
print("\n")

with open('circe_data.txt', 'a') as file:
  file.write(str(datetime.now()) + '\n')
  file.write('Temp (deg C): %.2f\n' %temp)
  file.write('Percent Humidity: %.2f\n\n' %humidity)

file.close()
```

Comment: that could just be a current directory difference. Try to hardcode the path to your file. BTW `file.close()` is useless, with block closes the file on exit.

Comment: What's the directory your IDE is running the script from? When you're running it from bash, `circle_data.txt` is resolving as `~/circle_data.txt`.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly doing a file.flush() after the file.write().

Comment: that's not required since the file is closed when exiting the with block. it's a current directory issue, else python would trigger an exception.

Comment: It was indeed the directory path. Hardcoding the path in worked. I thought that when it ran the script in it's own folder, the terminal would look in that folder, but I guess not. Thanks!